# i got an warning when i am uploading app non-public selectors in payload

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, itunes

I was added facebook share sdk `FB_IOS_SDK_VERSION_STRING @"3.23.1"` for facebook  integration purpose in my app i am using Feed dialogue and share dialogue methods as per Facebook documentation its working fine .But now i am uploading app in itunes i got a warning non-public selectors in payload/ content,setClient Version setContent Set EventName Set RequestId

see the image anyone know for this solution Please guide me...Advance Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to worry about that warning just ignore that, i also faced the same kind of warning in the app uploading process. I ignore that warning and My app is submitted for review it approved sucessfully.